# How to Access kendo-window from Angular Directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I have a kendo-window that I am trying to access from an Angular Directive; specifically I want to be able to pass a message to the window and use it (as a pop-up) but I can't get a handle on it. I've tried passing it to the directive as an argument in the same fashion that $filter/$timeout are passed (see below), and I've tried accessing it directly using code like:

```
var alertMessageWindow = element.find("#customWindow");
```

or

```
var alertMessageWindow = jQuery(element).find('#customWindow');
```

I'm definitely new to Angular Directives; so far the one I'm working with is working fine; I just can't access the kendo-window.

This is the basics of the code I am working with:

```
<div kendo-window="customWindow"
k-options="customWindowOptions">
</div>

appModule.directive("myDirective",['$filter','$timeout', 
function($filter, $timeout){
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        scope:{
            number:'=',
            max:'=?',
            min:'=?'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            //access kendo-window here
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

After continuing to research this and finding a great article here,
http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/

I found the solution; by changing the scope to false the directive (based on my reading) doesn't get reset, so referencing the kendo-window using,

```
scope.customWindow
```

Will now work.

```
appModule.directive("myDirective",['$filter','$timeout', 
function($filter, $timeout){
return {
    restrict:'A',
    scope:false,
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        //access kendo-window here using scope.customWindow
    }
};
}]);
```